# Detecting Android Wear Notification Dismiss Events

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

The Android Wear OS has recently been updated to 5.0, which includes the feature to "recover" the most recently dismissed notification.

As a consequence, a notification's [delete intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) is only triggered after the user can no longer recover the intent (after another notification is dismissed, or the user swipes down and lets the 'dismiss' timeout expire).

I am attempting to display a notification, which gets updated fairly regularly until the user dismisses it. For this, I need to know immediately when the user has dismissed the notification (before the "recover" option has expired), so that I can stop updating the notification. If I attempt to update the notification once it has been dismissed, it will launch a new notification. In effect, the notification can't be dismissed as it will be recreated immediately.

So my question is: Has anyone discovered a way to detect immediately when the user dismisses a notification on an Android Wear device, before the option to recover the notification expires? I suspect if such a method exists, it should also be possible to detect when the user recovers the notification.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Setting this flag will make it so the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it in the panel. The PendingIntent set with setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent) will be broadcast when the notification is canceled.

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder setAutoCancel (boolean autoCancel)
```

As I see it, it dismisses the notification immediately and it sends the setDeleteIntent() at the same time